# What do the trace map and determinant map mean in this context?

Tags: linear-transformations

For each of the following maps $T: \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\to \mathbb{R}$, determine whether $T$ is a linear transformation or not.

1. The trace map $T: M\to\mathrm{tr}(M)$
2. The determinant map $T: M\to\mathrm{det}(M)$.

If you could also give me an idea of how I go about cooing this,  that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: For (1) you must answer: is $\text{tr}(A+B)=\text{tr}(A)+\text{tr}(B)$ and $\text{tr}(\lambda\, A)=\lambda\,\text{tr}(A)$?

For (2) you must answer: is $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ and $\det(\lambda\, A)=\lambda\det(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

1. Let $T:M_{2\times M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
   be the function $T(A)=\text{tr}(A)$. 
   Since 
   \begin{align*}
   T(A+B) 
   &= \text{tr}(A+B) \\ 
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{2} ( a_{ii}+ b_{ii} )  \\ 
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{2} a_{ii}+ \sum_{i=1}^{2}  b_{ii} \\ 
   &= \text{tr}(A) + \text{tr}(B) \\ 
   &= T(A) + T(B)  
   \end{align*}
   and since 
   $$
   T(cA) = \text{tr}(cA) =  \sum_{i=1}^{2} ( c \: a_{ii} ) 
   = c \sum_{i=1}^{2}  a_{ii}  = c \: \text{tr}(A) =c\: T(A), 
   $$
   $T$ is a linear transformation.
2. No, $T(A) = \det(A)$ is not a linear transformation.

$\textbf{Counterexample}$: let 
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\mbox{ and let } 
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$ 
Then 
$$
T(A+B) = \det(A+B) = 0.  
$$
However, 
$$
T(A) + T(B) = \det(A) + \det(B) = 1 + 1 =2. 
$$
Since $T(A+B)\not=T(A)+ T(B)$, $T$ is not a linear transformation.